# Retrieve and print data from mysql DB using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following text fields -

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" tabindex="1">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1"/>
```

and the screenshot of mysql database is -

```
id          name
123         John
124         Rahi
```

When I insert the track id in the first text field then the corresponding student name should be shown in the second field. How can it be done using ajax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a jquery function on `onblur()` event of the textbox.

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" tabindex="1" onblur="getname()">
```

Write the ajax function for getting the name like:

```
<script>
function getname()
{
var id=$("#id").val();    // get the id from textbox
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        dataType:"text",
        data:"id="+id,
        url:"page.php",   // url of php page where you are writing the query
        success:function(response)
        { 
            $("#name").val(response);   // setting the result from page as value of name field

        }
        });

}
</script>
```

and write the code for fetching the result in a page, say **page.php**

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$query=mysql_query("select name from table where id=$id");
$result=mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo $result[0];    // echo the name to js function
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks its working for on blur. But actually i need the live value that means on keyup i need to show the name.

Comment: The same method you can use in any events. If so instead of onblur use keyup() event.

Comment: I just changed the function to onkeyup and its working. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user3055004..Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>> Trigger onblur event (javascript function) for the first textbox.
>> Define ajax in that function to get name.
>> Show the name in textbox.

I think this is simplest way to get this.
```

--
Thanks